Change color of labels and tick marks in pie chart in Base R
I have a pie chart:
x <- c(30, 70)
pie(x)

I want the labels to be red and the tick marks to be either red or transparent. How do I do that? xaxt = "n" and col.axis = "red" seem to have no effect.
pie(x, xaxt = "n", col.axis = "red")


You can change the colour of the ticks and labels by setting the col graphical parameter first:
opar <- par(col="red")
pie(x)


Then reset the color to the previous setting:
par(opar)


Great answer + 1. Note, that par(col="transparent") is also possible.

@jay.sf Yes - but then the labels would also be transparent, which the OP doesn't want, and I'm not sure if the colour of the ticks and labels can differ.

Sure, in this case we could use a hack like shown in my answer. Pie charts are overrated, however ;)

@jay.sf Pie charts are superior for what they do well (e.g. when there are only two slices whose sizes are significantly different, and when you want to show that the slices add up to 100 %). All other charts have similar problems, if you misuse them. For example, often the "other" category is not represented in bar graphs, overrepresenting the depicted categories. A bar graph of my data would leave you wondering if that is all the data there is or if I only showed two categories of many (e.g. NAs). The pie chart makes that clear. The question is always: What do you want to communicate?

@Edward's solution is great. For even more flexibility we could "hack" the pie function, something like:
> pie_hack <- 
+   function (x, labels = names(x), edges = 200, radius = 0.8, clockwise = FALSE, 
+             init.angle = if (clockwise) 90 else 0, density = NULL, angle = 45, 
+             col = NULL, border = NULL, lty = NULL, main = NULL, 
+             ticks.col = NULL, ticks.lab.col = NULL, ...) {
+     if (!is.numeric(x) || any(is.na(x) | x < 0)) 
+       stop("'x' values must be positive.")
+     if (is.null(labels)) 
+       labels <- as.character(seq_along(x))
+     else labels <- as.graphicsAnnot(labels)
+     x <- c(0, cumsum(x)/sum(x))
+     dx <- diff(x)
+     nx <- length(dx)
+     plot.new()
+     pin <- par("pin")
+     xlim <- ylim <- c(-1, 1)
+     if (pin[1L] > pin[2L]) 
+       xlim <- (pin[1L]/pin[2L]) * xlim
+     else ylim <- (pin[2L]/pin[1L]) * ylim
+     dev.hold()
+     on.exit(dev.flush())
+     plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", asp = 1)
+     if (is.null(col)) 
+       col <- if (is.null(density)) 
+         c("white", "lightblue", "mistyrose", "lightcyan", 
+           "lavender", "cornsilk")
+     else par("fg")
+     if (!is.null(col)) 
+       col <- rep_len(col, nx)
+     if (!is.null(border)) 
+       border <- rep_len(border, nx)
+     if (!is.null(lty)) 
+       lty <- rep_len(lty, nx)
+     angle <- rep(angle, nx)
+     if (!is.null(density)) 
+       density <- rep_len(density, nx)
+     twopi <- if (clockwise) 
+       -2 * pi
+     else 2 * pi
+     t2xy <- function(t) {
+       t2p <- twopi * t + init.angle * pi/180
+       list(x = radius * cos(t2p), y = radius * sin(t2p))
+     }
+     for (i in 1L:nx) {
+       n <- max(2, floor(edges * dx[i]))
+       P <- t2xy(seq.int(x[i], x[i + 1], length.out = n))
+       polygon(c(P$x, 0), c(P$y, 0), density = density[i], angle = angle[i], 
+               border = border[i], col = col[i], lty = lty[i])
+       P <- t2xy(mean(x[i + 0:1]))
+       lab <- as.character(labels[i])
+       if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
+         lines(c(1, 1.05) * P$x, c(1, 1.05) * P$y, 
+               col=if (!is.null(ticks.col)) ticks.col[i] else par("col"))  ## changed
+         text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
+              adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), 
+              col=if (!is.null(ticks.lab.col)) ticks.lab.col[i] else par("col"))  ## changed
+       }
+     }
+     title(main = main, ...)
+     invisible(NULL)
+   }
> 
> par(mfrow=c(2, 2), mar=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
> pie(x)
> cols <- hcl.colors(length(x))
> pie_hack(x, ticks.col=cols, ticks.lab.col=cols)
> pie_hack(x, ticks.col=c('red', 'blue'), ticks.lab.col=c('green', 'orange'))
> par(col='darkorange')
> pie_hack(x)


